# VK API сообщества

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Привет!

Для работы с пользователем есть рабочий метод `messages.getById` работает все ок.

Но, когда подключаю к `API` сообщество, делаю запрос- получаю личные сообщения, а не сообщения сообщества.

Для сообществ `messages.getById` не поддерживается?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Как говорит документация, возможно:

> Этот метод можно вызвать с ключом доступа сообщества. Требуются права
>   доступа: messages.

Или Вам надо получить сообщения с простого аккаунта от сообщества?

Comment: Да, я сгенерировал ключ сообщества, но вызываю messages.getById, указав id сообщения, получаю json из личных сообщений моего профиля

Comment: @АлександрИванов, потому что вы в запросе передаете свой токен, а не токен сообщества. В параметре `access_token` должен быть токен (ключ) сообщества.

Comment: А вот не правда, я передаю именно access_token сообщества

Comment: Только что на всякий случай сгенерировал новый, такая же ерунда.
Может быть нужно вызывать не messages.getById? @terron

Comment: Все нашел, спасибо! И правда)